# What is a "mo"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, slang

This short dialogue is from the movie Nick and Norah's Infinite Playlist:

> Norah: He's a complete **mo**, look at him.
>
> Caroline: He is not a **mo**. Look at how shitty he's dressed. His Supercuts haircut.

Considering this usage might be a slang, I checked Urban Dictionary but couldn't find anything that fits the context. I can only think of mo being short for modus operandi, but that is usually written as "M.O." I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's short for "homo", which is in turn short for "homosexual". Caroline cites gay stereotypes (good dressers, nice hair) and his lack of fulfilling them as evidence against Norah's assertion.